# CKAN: Unable to select the appropriate DataStore columns for the axis of a graph-based view

Tags: ckan

Let's say I have the following resource in `demo.ckan.org`:

http://demo.ckan.org/dataset/sc_malaga_traffic/resource/a43bfb04-7a8b-4624-a06a-25f4165e5b2f

If I try to create a view, I've found that I'm unable to select the desired columns both for the Axis 1 and 2. Only "_id", "recvTime" and "rectTimeTs" are available:

[image]

[image]

I would like to use "attrValue" as the column for Axis 2.

Maybe I'm not understanding well how the views work, so an explanation will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is "attrValue" numeric or something else, or perhaps a mixture. Non-numeric columns are an issue: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2591

Comment: P.S. The quick hack if this is only for display purposes is to modify the JSON-formatted config in the DB...

Comment: Hi Matt, `attrValue` is non-numeric, right. And can you elaborate a bit more on that hack, please?

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to see your comment and now only got to getting back to you

Answer (score 1):

There are two "fixes"; neither are particularly nice:

1. Apply this change/commit to your CKAN source: https://github.com/smartlane/ckan/commit/9a72192e8e108a408124c36e58ad48fd09f0dd6f
2. Create your view with any old axis 1 and axis 2 (even though these aren't the variables you want). Connect to the CKAN database and go to the resource_view table, find the row with id of the view you just created (click through to it in CKAN and you'll see it at the end of the URL). Edit the "config" column - it is text in JSON format. Set series and group to the actual attributes/column names of the data that you want instead of the dummy ones you entered.